# Continuous bijection between open simply connected subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ are open sets.  I did a proof saying if $U$ and $V$ were conformally equivalent then $U$ simply connected implies $V$ is as well.  I did this by showing the conformal map between the two was a homeomorphism.  However, the problem has a side note saying that it would have been enough to have a continuous bijection rather than holomorphic bijection between the two sets.  I don't see why this is the case.  Can someone explain why this was enough as I used the holomorphicity in my proof?

Comment: What did you use the holomorphicity for? Simple connectedness is a topological property, so it is preserved under homeomorphisms; a continuous injective map between open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ is a homeomorphism between the domain and image.

Comment: @DanielFischer how do I know your last statement?  I say the same statement you do except I say holomorphic injective map and justify my statement via the open mapping theorem giving me a continuous inverse.  How do you get your continuous inverse?

Comment: That is the invariance of domain. Unsurprisingly, it's much harder to prove for merely continuous functions. If the note had said "homeomorphism" instead of "continuous bijection", would it then have been clear to you that that suffices, that one doesn't need a conformal (hence holomorphic) bijection?

Comment: Yes of course.  That was how I proved it was by showing I had a homeomorphism.  I was just missing the continuous inverse part here aka open map. Thanks

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. That property of continuous injections and open subsets of some $\mathbb{R}^n$ is decidedly non-trivial, and one isn't expected to know it before having learned topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the invariance of domain http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain to show that the continuous bijection is a homeo into the image, so that the image is simply-connected.

Comment: But that is probably overkill.

Comment: If you have something simpler and better, I'd gladly hear it.